# Can't see all the stack trace for failure trace in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to show full stack trace on eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597797/how-to-show-full-stack-trace-on-eclipse)

I've got an error with a TestRunner setup that I'm trying to debug.  Using Eclipse with JUnit, and I need to see the entire stack trace.  It's proving impossible to find the issue without being able to see the exception.

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.mockito.internal.exceptions.stacktrace.ConditionalStackTraceFilter.<init>(ConditionalStackTraceFilter.java:17)
at org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException.filterStackTrace(MockitoException.java:30)
at org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException.<init>(MockitoException.java:19)
```

...

```
org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:29)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:24)
at org.junit.internal.requests.FilterRequest.getRunner(FilterRequest.java:33)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.<init>(JUnit4TestReference.java:33)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestMethodReference.<init>(JUnit4TestMethodReference.java:25)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:54)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

**How can I see the 57 more?**

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.mockito.internal.exceptions.stacktrace.StackTraceFilter.<clinit>(StackTraceFilter.java:21)
... 57 more
```

Comment: 57 more... would be again repetition of almost same stack trace.

Comment: This should be your whole stack trace. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597797/how-to-show-full-stack-trace-on-eclipse) SO question