# How do I show the rest of the errors in LogCat

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

I am using logcat to debug an android application and it seems to cut off before showing me where the actual problem is. the last line says:
`06-02 17:48:34.703: E/AndroidRuntime(2982):    ... 11 more`
How do show the rest of the errors?

Comment: This is not a restriction of LogCat, but one of Java stack traces in general: [How to show full stack trace on eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597797/how-to-show-full-stack-trace-on-eclipse)

Answer (score 1):

There is a `Save` button in `LogCat Panel`. It will expport in text file where you want.

Comment: https://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/how-to-1/save-logcat-to-a-text-file